# ajax: Is it possible to "POST" and "GET" at the same time?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, post, get

I am trying to create a form:

 1/ when user type in their name, and their name is within the API, it would print their name and info accordingly(`GET`); whereas

 2/ if their name is not on the API, it would print their name (`GET`) and as well as create a new row on the API with their name (`POST`) and assign a new `id` for them accordingly.

For example:

1/ If "Alexis" is typed (It is a name within the API), it would print "Alexis" and information about him.

2/ If "Karen" is typed (the name is not in the API), it would print "Karen", add a new id (if id[5] is the end of the list, "Karen" would now be id[6]) and row on the API and print a generic information about her.

I was trying to send the `GET` within the `POST` function and wonder if that is the correct method please? Cos it is not working at all now...

**[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/cpqrt1x3/4/)**

Cheers,

Karen

Answer (score 0):

Sure you Can. Simply put your GET variablesi n your POST url

```
var id = 1;
var name = "Tom";

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/passwords/add?user=" + id,
            data: {
                name: name 
            }
        });
```